# JSON parsing when nodes are dynamic

Tags: json, parsing

Looking to parse the below JSON. Here dynamic1 and dynamic2 changes based on the value present in "id" and "idext" respectively. In runtime, we could get any value for it. As I'm finding difficulty in defining json schema as the nodes are dynamic how json parsing can be done to extract the values from below json message.

```
    {
     "id":"dynamic1",
 "idext":"dynamic2",

       "details":{
       "description":"this is the description",

           "dynamic1":{ <-- this would change based on the value in 'id'
           "param1":"100",
           "param2":"101",
           "param3":"102"
        },

       "dynamic2":{ <-- this would change based on the value in 'idext'
           "param4":"200",
           "param5":"201",
           "param6":"202"
        },
 }
}
```

that is Id and idext can be anything at runtime making the complete JSON inner object to be dynamic as below..it could be like literally anything at runtime.. How do I define a Jason parsor to extract the complete object or even within the object like param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6

```
    {
     "id":"john",
     "idext":"peter",

       "details":{
       "description":"this is the description",

           "john":{ <-- this would change based on the value in 'id'
           "param1":"100",
           "param2":"101",
           "param3":"102"
        },

       "peter":{ <-- this would change based on the value in 'idext'
           "param4":"200",
           "param5":"201",
           "param6":"202"
        },
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance...
John

Comment: I mean it could have any value based on the value comes in id or idext... Say id = john idext=peter then it would like

Comment: I mean it could have any value based on the value comes in id or idext... Say id = john idext=peter and the inner node name would change based on that. The problem is at runtime id and idext can have any abc or xyz value. How do I define a Jason parsor to extract the complete object or even within the object like param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6

Comment: Like below.      {
     "id":"john",
 "idext":"peter",

       "details":{
       "description":"this is the description",

           "john":{ <-- this would change based on the value in 'id'
           "param1":"100",
           "param2":"101",
           "param3":"102"
        },

       "peter":{ <-- this would change based on the value in 'idext'
           "param4":"200",
           "param5":"201",
           "param6":"202"
        },
 }
}

Comment: Clearer now! I'm still missing what tools you expect to use for parsing?

Comment: any json parsor like jackson or so my be in spring framework,,

Comment: OK. Then now what if you add the tag `java` to the question and include a block of code showing what have you tried, explaining why it does not work. That would make your question less broad and easier to answer